# VSCode create file with extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to build a `VSCode-Extension` that will generate a `Dart` file (Path is where the extension method is called).

I followed the [Official Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) and then I tried to create a file.

This is what I tried to create a simple `.dart` file:

```
function activate(context) {

    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "flutter-localization-generator" is now active!');

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('flutter-localization-generator.create', function () {

        // create a stream to be named data.js
        const file = fs.createWriteStream(
            resolve(__dirname, 'localization_config.dart')
        );
    
        // manually write some text to file
        file.write('// This is a test.');
    
        // close the stream
        file.end();

        // Display a message box to the user
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Created!');
        
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```

However this is not creating anything. `.showInformationMessage` is working just fine. But no file is created.

What am I missing here? How can I create a `file` at the current path with a `VSCode-Extension` ?

Comment: to be able to work with remote workspaces use `vscode.workspace.fs`

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```js
const fileName = 'localization_config.dart';
const wsEdit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
const wsPath = (vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders as vscode.WorkspaceFolder[])[0].uri.fsPath;
const filePath = vscode.Uri.file(wsPath + fileName);
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(filePath.toString());
wsEdit.createFile(filePath, { ignoreIfExists: true });
vscode.workspace.applyEdit(wsEdit);
vscode.window.showInformationMessage('created a new file:' + fileName);
```

Comment: how do you add content to the file?

Comment: using .insert method